# Session variable being dropped when using rewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a strange thing happening.  If I go to my site's main landing page, then click through and add a product to the shopping cart, a PHP session variable called 'cartID' is saved. That way a customer can continue to add items to their cart without losing their cart items.

If I bypass the main landing page and go straight to a product page (like via a bookmark or google search), then add that item to the shopping cart, although the session variable 'cartID' is created, once the customer leaves the cart page, the 'cartID' variable is lost...which empties their cart.

Both methods of adding an item(s) to the cart use a rewriteRule in .htaccess:

> RewriteRule ^g(.*)c(.*)s(.*)ss(.*)p(.*)/(.*).htm$ onlineOrder.php?grpid=$1&catSel=$2&subCat1ID=$3&subCat2ID=$4&prodSel=$5&$6 [QSA]

Which works fine, but the 'cartID' session variable created once an item is added to the shopping cart will get lost when leaving the cart page if the customer didn't go to the main landing page first.  Even though both links to the product page are the exact same.

Any idea as to why it doesn't work if going straight to a product page?

Comment: Check that the session ID is remaining constant throughout. If you've got wonky cookie settings, you could be getting a new clean session each time, causing variables to get "lost".

Comment: Do you call session_start() at the pages you want to access the session? Also check if you date_time zone is set correctly so you are not expiring your sessions immediately.

Comment: I am using session_start() at the pages I want to access the session.  I just checked and found that when starting from the main landing page, the session ID remains the same on all pages.  When going directly to a product page, the session ID changes on every single page I go to from that point. Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is one or more of your pages may be sending output before `session_start();` is called.

Make sure there are no lines, blank spaces, or anything else before the initial `<?php` and that nothing is outputted *before* `session_start();` is called (this includes `header();` lines, as they produce output). Basically, starting the session should be one of the first things your script does, if not the first.